# _.pluck of Backbone collection not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have this model -

```
class pt.SearchResultModel extends Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    id:"",
    image:"",
    colour:""
```

I am trying this -

```
_.pluck(resultsCollection,'id')
```

But it keeps returning undefined - not sure what's going on.

What syntax error am I making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Underscore array methods are embedded (so to speak) into Backbone collections. You can call them directly on them:

```
resultsCollection.pluck 'id'
```

In most of the cases you could also use the Underscore methods over the collection's `models` attribute (which is a plain-old array), like `_.pluck someCollection.models, 'someAttr'`, but notice that the case of `pluck` is special, as Backbone models will usually not have their attributes as own properties (you have to call [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) to access them). The implementation of Backbone's `pluck` is [very straightforward](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/c19459a816674502d8d244bcd962df983e2c8b09/backbone.js#L746) nevertheless :)

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you can use the [pluck](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-pluck) method of your collection directly which delegates to underscore's [pluck](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck) method.

However I noticed that if for example you [filter](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) your collection you will end up with a plain array of models and as such don't have the *collection's* `pluck` method. In this case what you can do is first pluck the `attributes` attribute and then pluck the `id` for example something like this should work

`_.pluck(_.pluck(myCollection, 'attributes'), 'id');`

Of course you can also just  create a new collection and pass in these models and then have access to the collections `pluck` method.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
resultsCollection.pluck('id');
```

Underscore methods on Backbone collections are used in this way and not in their original form `_.method()`

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Collection` automatically provides a good part of `underscore.js` functions. So you can write `resultsCollection.pluck('id')`, which is a bit better.

Now, about your question : `pluck` uses 'get' internally to retrieve your attributes. This, plus your result means that your model does not have `id` defined as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `_.pluck(resultsCollection,'id')`, you call the pluck method on the collection object.
This collection has a **models** attribute, but no **id** attribute.

That's why it's much more better to call `resultsCollection.pluck('id')` wich will do all the work for you :

- go to **models** attribute
- go to each **attributes** attribute of each model
- find the wanted **id** value and put it into the result array