# Retrieving a specific element from a Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider the following backbone collection:
[image]

What I would like to do is access the field 'name'. Here's what I did:

```
this._selectedNodes.pluck('name').forEach((objectName) => {
    $objectListLi.append(`<li>${objectName}</li>`);
});
```

But I keep getting "undefined" as result. What's even weirder is that when I loop through the collection using "id" instead, I get the result.

Any idea why is this happening and how I can fix it?

***EDIT***:

Notice here that the 'id' is already present in the first layer under models:
[image]

However, the 'name' field is only present under attributes:
[image]

Could this be the reason why pluck is not able to find 'name'? Maybe pluck is only able to go a level below?

**EDIT 2**:

I tried the same thing but with map instead of pluck:

```
this._selectedNodes.map(function(model){
return model.get('name');})
```

Same thing, I got undefined. So this rules out the possibility of pluck being the problem.

**EDIT 3**:

```
Got it work like this:
this._selectedNodes.map(function(model){
return model.attributes.get('name');})
```

Now, I get the value of the name. However, I'm still unable to integrate it in the foreach loop. Any idea?

Comment: When you run that statement, it will return 'undefined', however it should still append an li for each name from each model in the collection. What is the value of $objectListLi after that statement?

Comment: Thank you for your time. It's undefined as well. But I noticed something that caught my attention. I'm going to update my original post.

Comment: Have you confirmed that $objectListLi is defined before you run your map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it work. I removed pluck and used map instead. The solution is not very elegant, but that's the only one that worked for me.

```
        var names = this._selectedNodes.map(function (model) {
        return model.attributes.get('name');
    });

    names.forEach(function (objectName) {
        $objectListLi.append(`<li>${objectName}</li>`);
    });
```

I hope it'll help someone else, and thanks for everyone who tried to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

At some stage it seems your name is becoming undefined? Maybe do a check for that.
For all nodes is the property of 'name' always available?

```
  this._selectedNodes.pluck('name').forEach((objectName) => {
      if (objectName !== 'undefined') // Any scope
            $objectListLi.append(`<li>${objectName}</li>`);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added the condition but I still get undefined.

But the 'name' field is defined and has 'JOB_0' as value. That's why I'm confused here. It's like he's not even detecting it.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but maybe you need to use an accessor to access other attributes apart from id - https://backbonejs.org/#Model-get.

Comment: This question may be of help too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402146/pluck-of-backbone-collection-not-working